# trend regression

Tags: regression, trend

Suppose I want to include a trend term and the interaction of a predictor with a trend in a regression. Does it make a difference (in terms of the estimated coefficient as tstat) whether:

1) I define the trend as [1 2 3 4 ...] or as [4 5 6 7 8 ...] ?

2) Suppose I define a trend and interact with a predictor. There are 100 periods,say. But I have missing data for the predictor for period 47. Would it be more appropriate to define a trend as [1 2 3 ... 46 48 49 50 ...100] or as [1 2 3 ... 99] ?

thanks

Comment: No; the slope and its SE are the same. Indeed, in a common case of response and calendar year fitting a trend in terms of say (calendar year $-$ 2000), or more generally relative to a key date within the data, is often preferable. Otherwise the intercept is for year 0, a date not usually within the data (quite apart from the pedantic detail that 1 BCE preceded 1 CE).

Comment: On 2) gaps should never make you change the time variable. it's 1... 100.

Comment: @Nick Generally, yes--but I believe there are important exceptions, such as handling weekends in time series of stock market transactions.

Comment: @whuber Agreed; if something like a business calendar operates then in effect the clock may be considered switched off when nothing is happening. That didn't sound like the situation here, but my "never" should be "never without sound independent reason".